How encode special character without causing error in httpclient angular
I have a data id value STUDENT/STUD01 then I'm trying to encode the "/" but it cause an error in httpclient if its not encoded it will create a new path.
what I try is use the encodeURI(data.id) and encodeURIComponent(data.id)
    const data = cloneDeep(this.form);
let url = this.getAPI();
url += `/${encodeURI(data.id)}`

    this.http.post(url, data).subscribe((.) => {....});

or
const data = cloneDeep(this.form); let url = this.getAPI(); url += `/${encodeURIComponent(data.id)}`

this.http.post(url, data).subscribe((.) => {....});

but it cause an error which
Request URL: https://localhot:8080/api/list/STUDENT%STUD01  Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin


From your URL, this seems the encoding for "/" not working correctly, it should be "%2F" after encoded (with encodeURIComponent()). https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

@YongShun, please check the image

You could try splitting the ID at the forward slash, encode each part separately using encodeURIComponent() and then join the encoded parts back together with a forward slash, something like this :
    const data = cloneDeep(this.form);
    let url = this.getAPI();
    
    const encodedId = data.id.split('/').map(part => encodeURIComponent(part)).join('/');
    
    url += `/${encodedId}`;
    
    this.http.post(url, data).subscribe((response) => {.....});


if it will put it back, it will create a new path which it cause an error
